# How do I Modify my Workspace Listing in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-apps-script, marketplace

**How do I modify a Google Marketplace Overview text for a published app?**

I have a published addon which is fully approved/verified and is visible in the Marketplace.
However, I would like to modify the Overview text as it appears in the marketplace (I do not need to modify any images).

I can modify parts of the listing via [Google Cloud Platform->APIs and Services->Google Workspace Marketplace SDK->App Configuration | Store Listing], but there appears to be no mechanism to modify the listing "Overview" text.

I even tried an UNPUBLISH to see if this would allow modification, but no luck.
I am sure there must be a way but all documentation simply points me to the Marketplace SDK.

Thanks for any pointers.

/Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing here?

[image]

Store Listing > App Details > Language (open list) > Short Description || Detailed Description

Comment: Well do I feel stupid.  I completely missed the expansion V.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer